# how to submit form iframe WYSIWYG in php page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I made my WYSIWYG editor and I am trying to get the value of WYSIWYG editor but not working, 
I have a PHP script and I am trying to insert WYSIWYG  in that script and get the value in the form .
this is  the almost all of page  WYSIWYG

```js
var showingSourceCode = false;
var isInEditMode = true;

function enableDesignMode() {
  ritchTextFiled.document.designMode = 'on';
}

function exeCmd(command) {
  ritchTextFiled.document.execCommand(command, null, false);
}

function execCommandWithArg(command, arg) {
  ritchTextFiled.document.execCommand(command, null, arg);
}

function toggleSource() {
  if (showingSourceCode) {
    ritchTextFiled.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = ritchTextFiled.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent;
    showingSourceCode = false;
  } else {
    ritchTextFiled.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent = ritchTextFiled.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
    showingSourceCode = true;
  }
}

function toggleEdit() {
  if (isInEditMode) {
    ritchTextFiled.document.designMode = 'off';
    isInEditMode = false;
  } else {
    ritchTextFiled.document.designMode = 'on';
    isInEditMode = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript</title>

  <body onload="enableDesignMode();" style="width: 628px;">
    <button onclick="toggleSource();"><b>< / ></b></button>
    <button onclick="exeCmd('bold');"><b>B</b></button>

    <iframe name="ritchTextFiled" style=" width: 100%;height: 300px;border: 1px solid #2b9ff6; 
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(42, 53, 71, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(42, 53, 71, 0.19); ">
</iframe>
```

and the primary page for the form this

```
if(is_post_request()) {

// Create record using post parameters
$args= $_POST['topic'];
$topic = new Topic($args);
$result = $topic->save();

if($result === true) {

  $session->message('The Topic was created successfully.');
  redirect_to(url_for("topic.php"));
} else {
  // show errors
  $session->message('The Topic was created Error.');
  redirect_to(url_for("topic.php"));
}

} else {


}

?>



<form action="<?php echo url_for('ntopic.php'); ?>" method="post">
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
<label for="pagetitle"> Page Titel</label>
<input id="pagetitle" type="text" class="" name="topic[topic_title]" style="width: 96.4%;padding: 10px;font-size: 18px;">
</div>



    <iframe src="WYSIWYG.php" style="width:100%;height:500px;border:0px;background:red;" title="">
    </iframe>


<input type="submit" style="width:100.4%;padding:10px;background:#2a3547;color:#2b9ff6; border:0px;
font
" value="Publish">
</form>
```

I want to get the value of WYSIWYG in $_POST['topic']; 
I try to be as clear as possible, Sorry for the disturbance .

Comment: Ypu have a nested iframe in a form and expect the content to be posted to PHP?

Comment: I am sorry, i trying to get help.

Comment: and that not all the code I am trying to anyone understand the idea

Comment: But the idea is really not recommended coding. You do not need iFrame for your code at all.

Comment: Instead use the PHP to INCLUDE WYSIWYG.php in the main page and on save, ajax the values from a content editable DIV or a tinymce editor to the backend

Comment: if i didn't use iframe in WYSIWYG  i can't type inside the editor and see the style at the same time

Comment: ok i will trying to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made new Question more clear than that and found the answer Thank you.
[Soultion of this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62486822/4348206)