# How to get value of WYSIWYG and insert it in textarea Tag by Javascript only?

Tags: javascript, html

how to get the value of WYSIWYG and insert it in Textarea Tag by Javascript only?

```js
<script>
        // insert value in texatarea
        function frm() {
       var x = document.getElementById("tgt").contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body").value;
       document.getElementById("val1").innerHTML = x;
     }
     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // WYSIWYG2
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    var showingSourceCode = false;
        var isInEditMode= true;
    
        function enableDesignMode(){
            ritchTextFiled.document.designMode='on';
        }
        function exeCmd(command){
            ritchTextFiled.document.execCommand(command,null,false);
        }
    
        function execCommandWithArg(command,arg){
            ritchTextFiled.document.execCommand(command,null,arg);
        }
    
        function toggleSource(){
            if(showingSourceCode){
            ritchTextFiled.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML= ritchTextFiled.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent;
            showingSourceCode=false;
        }else{
            ritchTextFiled.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].textContent= ritchTextFiled.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
            showingSourceCode=true;
            }
        }
    
        function toggleEdit(){
            if(isInEditMode){
                ritchTextFiled.document.designMode='off';
                isInEditMode=false;
            }else{
                ritchTextFiled.document.designMode='on';
                isInEditMode=true;
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<body onload="enableDesignMode();">
<textarea name="textval1" id="val1">

</textarea>

<iframe  id='tgt' name="ritchTextFiled" onkeyup="frm()" > </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

I try most of the solution on the internet but all using jquery or javascript not working,
Please try to find the solution by javascript only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best solution found until now by Javascript is :

```
   var iframe = document.getElementById("tgt");
   var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
   document.getElementById("val1").innerHTML=innerDoc.body.innerHTML;
```

Thank you.